# Are algorithms for searching text vs searching numbers fundamentally different?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, strings, matching

I face this problem a lot while searching phone numbers and bank account numbers, when I do remember it partially.

I save a draft in gmail with the content `I am mango`. Then I search it, by entering just `mango` and it gets me to the draft.

But when I save a draft with some number such as `123987645` and try to search by entering `12398764` i.e just one character missing I fail to find it. Also I failed when I just typed  `87645`.

Out of curiosity I am asking are the algorithms for finding numbers and text fundamentally different? Or I am missing something?

Comment: I edited your question to be ontopic here; nobody besides Google engineers know how they do it, but we can make educated guesses and talk about fundamentals.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for editing. I was thinking that the screenshots will give some more clarity.

Comment: I did not think so. All they provide is "proof" of Google behaving his way, but that is not as important here is would be on, say, [SU].

Comment: What is unexpected there ? In both cases you are matching exact words, be they formed of letters or digits, and the search engine returns those it finds !? I don't see different behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to assume that numbers and words are treated differently: for their servers, both are just strings. Different behaviour would be *extra* work and I don't see why that would be useful here.

There is one possible explanation for the behaviour you see: maybe they don't search for parts of words!

It is easy to preprocess texts so that finding whole words is fast. Well, looking for *any* substring is not that much slower (cf [suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)) but it generates more data to store. Given the amount of data Google deals with, they might have a numbered dictionary and save tuples like `(msg_id, position, word_id)` (or similar)¹. Storing (matches for) all substrings would cause this data set to explode! (And don't even think about [approximate search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)!)

You can try and verify this by searching not for `mango` but for `ngo` -- does it still find your message?

---

1. I'm quite sure Google does something far more clever.